# Python. Making many web requests in thousands of threads

Tags: python, multithreading, request

I need to write an application what has 20000-30000 threads and each of them should send approximately 100 asynchronous requests per minute through different proxies.

And my questions are:

-Will it be possible to run this app on machine with 8-16 RAM?

-Is it okay to use python threading and asyncio libraries for this purpose? Maybe there are some better ways to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Try writing a program that starts 20,000 threads that do nothing but sleep and see what happens. I think asyncio sounds like a good option for this. Understand that asyncio is essentially an alternative to threads, you wouldn't use both.

Comment: I'll recommend to use multiprocessing. may I ask what is the use-case here?

Comment: thanks to everyone for response!

@MuhammadMoizAhmed of course:) it's a viewer bot for some streaming platform

Comment: welcome @molekulo. shouldn't you be thinking of addressing it via any streaming solutions insstead of so many async requests?

Comment: @MuhammadMoizAhmed what do you mean? something like this http://docs.livestreamer.io/ ?